# AngularJS select not showing model object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

AngularJS doesn't seem to be showing my default value (model) for select if I hard code in an object value like the following.

**html**:

```
<select ng-model="defaultOption" ng-options="o.vala for o in options"></select>
```

**javascript**:

```
$scope.options = [ 
    {vala: "value1a", valb: "value1b"}, 
    {vala: "value2a", valb: "value2b"} 
];
$scope.defaultOption = {vala: "value1a", valb: "value1b"};
```

Yet if I change `$scope.defaultOption` to `$scope.options[0]`, I get my default option showing on the select no problem.

Why is this happening, and is there a way I can keep

`$scope.defaultOption = {vala: "value1a", valb: "value1b"};`

instead of using the indirect referencing?

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/64ycY/8/

(uncomment the other $scope.defaultOption for comparison)

Comment: I think it is because angularjs is looking for object equality here

Comment: @ArunPJohny is right. You could create a function (or take from underscore.js) and use _that_ to find the element matching your object in `$scope.options`.

Comment: @Dogbert An example would be great if you could provide one. I don't quite know how I could make angularjs reference a function when using select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one possible solution, as discussed in the question comments above, using underscore.js (could just really be done with a small function instead of pulling in underscore.js)

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MainController', function($scope) {
    $scope.options = [ 
        {vala: "value1a", valb: "value1b"}, 
        {vala: "value2a", valb: "value2b"} 
    ];
    var setDefaultOption = function(option) {
        $scope.defaultOption = _.findWhere($scope.options, option);
    }
    setDefaultOption({vala: "value1a", valb: "value1b"});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Dogbert/64ycY/9/

Comment: Underscore is great, however it could be an overkill just for this. See a native solution here: http://jsfiddle.net/Zmetser/57Vk4/

Comment: @OlivérKovács, I think your code is just comparing one property, while OP wants to match all properties of the object.

Comment: you are right, my solution assumes that every item has its own ID. If this assumption is not correct, it won't work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I was expecting that all properties of the object match as you've assumed. Thanks!